Jatayu telling Ravana the source of his strength - which version of Ramayana has this?
I am watching a serial on Ramayana in which Ravana tricks Jatayu as Jatayu tries to stop him from abducting Sita.  As the fight seems headed to a stalemate, Ravana suggests that they should both tell the other the source of their strength.  As I recall, Jatayu says truthfully that his strength comes from his wings, but Ravana lies about his own strength and defeats Jatayu.
Is this in any version of Ramayana or is it just poetic license?
